# Is it good idea to use Capped Collections for reading the queries with few index defined

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I wanted to insert around 4 million of record in the normal collection. But the bulk insert was very slow, so I have created Capped Collections and loaded my data. Someone suggested to me that there will not any performance impact so no need to create the indexes.

But I am seeing for fetching the first 25 records with some filtering taking lots of time. I have a few questions to understand it better.

1. What is the ideal situation where Capped Collections are suggested
2. Can I create a compound index on the Capped Collections
3. Any performance improvement with Capped Collections over the normal collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A capped collection limits how much data it stores. It does not make retrieval of the data it does store any faster.

Generally if you need fast (or, realistically, reasonably performant) reads you should be using indexes.